# How can I indicate the bounding box using .bb files in \includegraphics?

Tags: latex, bounding-box

Is it possible to use a .bb file (generated with, for instance, the "ebb" program included in MiKTeX) to define the bounding box of .png files when using `\includegraphics`?

I can define the bounding box in the optional argument to `\includegraphics` directly, like `\includegraphics[bb=0 0 100 100]{file.png}`, but I'd like to be able to define this outside of the code, using the generated .bb file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. Applying

```
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png, .bb}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.png}{eps}{.bb}{}
```

before including graphics using `\includegraphics{file}` (without the extension) solved it. :)

Just in case someone have the same problem.